# Grouping Data first by frequency, then by category in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, grouping

I have a large csv file, which is a log of caller data.

An example of my file:

```
CompanyName    High Priority     QualityIssue
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer2         No              User
Customer3         No              Equipment
Customer1         No              Neither
Customer3         No              User
Customer3         Yes             User
Customer3         Yes             Equipment
Customer4         No              User
```

My code can currently sort the data so I can get the top caller.

However, what I need next is to find for that caller the count of their types of calls. Then format a csv like below:

```
Top Calling Customers,         Equipment,    User,    Neither,
Customer 3,                      2,           2,        0,
Customer 1,                      0,           2,        1,
Customer 2,                      0,           1,        0,
Customer 4,                      0,           1,        0,
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of groupby, Counters, and loops but I cannot for the life of me get past the first column.

Here is the code I have to sort the Top Calling Customers:

```
 data = pandas.read_csv('Copy of HEAT Data.csv', delimiter =',')
 TopCustomerCallers = data['CompanyName'].value_counts()
```

However, the original issue remains, I have to now use the TopCustomerCallers to count up the QualityIssue and sort it. Hope this question makes sense.

edit: took out an example file with completely irrelevant information in it and added a new example. Also took out previous 70 lines of code and replaced with a two liner that I figured out after asking the question.

Edit: More example data. Real data is over 5000 rows long and goes to column AA but I'm only interested in frequency of customer and their types of calls. 
[image: Example Data]

Comment: start by indenting your code properly. Python is very sensitive to indentation. The lines of code within the functions must be indented (i.e. tabbed/spaced) under the function

Comment: I have indented it and submitted an edit to your post. Please check it is correct

Comment: Thanks Pynchia. You're right, the indenting didn't transfer when I pasted it over so it got sloppy. I realized that I can do my entire code above in just one line: data = pandas.read_csv('Copy of HEAT Data.csv', delimiter =',')

TopCustomerCallers = data['CompanyName'].value_counts()

So next would be some kind of forloop through the original file, pulling TopCustomerCallers and counting the quality issues for each? This is the part I am unsure about.

Comment: @Pynchia I edited the code to reflect the indents and also pasted in the new code that should replace that mess.

Comment: Wait do you actually want your output to have bacterium and antibacterial agents' names in it?

Comment: @ap No, that was just an example of the format I'm going for. Ultimately it'll be a list with the customers with the most frequency in the first column, and in each customer's row there will be its count for the number of User, Equipment, or Neither type of calls.

Comment: Okay, that's... a little confusing. Sounds like you want a dict of companynames with counts `{companyname: (UserCount, EquipmentCount, NeitherCount)}` -- is that roughly correct?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Does that help @Pynchia and @ap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the data sorted using:

```
import csv
import pandas
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

data = pandas.read_csv(filename.csv', delimiter =',')
byqualityissue = data.groupby(["CompanyName","QualityIssue"]).size()
```

But not in the format I want, and then it's not sorting by the top number of callers.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

counts = defaultdict(lambda: {"User": 0, "Equipment": 0, "Neither": 0})
with open('filename.tsv', 'rb') as fh: 
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter='\t') # assuming it's formatted like your example above
    for row in reader: 
        company, calltype = row[0], row[2]
        counts[company][calltype] += 1
```

At this point, you have something that looks like this:

```
In [14]: dict(counts)
Out[14]:
{'Customer1': {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 1, 'User': 2},
 'Customer2': {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 1},
 'Customer3': {'Equipment': 2, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 2},
 'Customer4': {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 1}}
```

Depending on how you want this output structured, it might be as easy as a call to `csv.DictWriter`, or you might want to leverage [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to sort items before writing them.

Edit: So for instance, to turn this defaultdict into an OrderedDict, you could do:

```
sorted_counts = OrderedDict(sorted(counts.iteritems(), key=lambda counts_tup: sum(counts_tup[1].values())))
```

Comment: That output looks a lot like I want it! Can I format the dict into a csv? I'm getting this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ed87ced5e864>", line 1, in <module>
    dict(dd)

    NameError: name 'dd' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I renamed it earlier and didn't update. See edit.

Comment: Threw in a quick example of how to order. You can do `-sum` for a reverse ordering. Don't know that bokeh cares about the order so much, but in case it does, there you go.

Comment: Gotcha, thought it might be that. I fixed that bug but I'm now getting running into a problem with the count. There are multiple columns and Customers is 1, and Quality issue is the 9th column. My code is stopping because it's running into the next column and showing a KeyError. 


 File "U:/TopCustomerCallersCounter.py", line 26, in <module>
    counts[CompanyName][QualityIssue] += 1

KeyError: 'CallerName'                (Where the third column's name is CallerName)

Comment: This happens even if I change CompanyName, QualityIssue = row[1], row[9] Except the KeyError shows as 'QualityIssue' instead.

Comment: Are company and issue really 1 and 9? Not, say, 0 and 8? I'd need more example data to know what's going wrong for sure, sorry.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the data. Does that help?

Comment: Found out that it was reading the header, which is why it was giving me that error. Added headerline = reader.next() under the reader and it works now! Thanks @ap!